# creating child terms from a parent using fields

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

For a project i would like to achieve the following:

Using 2 fields in a content type
field_parent  = reference to term 
This field references to vocabulary 'parent terms'

I have a second field called 'field_child'.
This field has to be a child term of the 'field_parent' term

sample:
field_parent --> apples
field_child --> green

in taxonomy I see
Apples
- green
Pears
- green

How can I achieve this? Is there any module available or snippet.

Comment: Max be the conditional fields module is helpfull for you: http://drupal.org/node/1349882#comment-6190164

Comment: Have you already build out your vocabulary as a hierarchical (parent-child) vocabulary or are they separate?  If they're separate, is anything keeping you from just having these be two separate term reference fields?

Comment: @betaride you sent me to the rules page.. not sure what to do there.

Comment: @boriana my taxonomy is built by tag field (term reference field) in the node form.
i have 2 term field referencing to the same vocabulary.
I had testedthe following code: http://blog.yawd.eu/2011/how-automatically-add-taxonomy-relations-drupal-7/
that works for single node creations.
But when using it with my feed mapping is get an error.
"Missing bundle property on entity of type taxonomy_term." I just cant get to create parent->child term relations on the fly with my imported feeds.
If anyone has something lying around maybe for a small donation i'd be delighted.

Comment: [Taxonomy Term Reference Tree widget](http://drupal.org/project/term_reference_tree) allows you to select either the lowest level in a hierarchy or to select its parents as well automatically.

Comment: hi beth, 
I have been lookin into that, but i cant seem to create child items from the create node form. my vocabulry is just a lng list or terms created in the node form without a tree.
my field_subcategory, should be a child of field_category by default.

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is with doing this via feeds (from your comment to me), I'd try the following:

It looks like you're already using the feeds module and that your incoming terms are mapped to your term reference.  Good!  It also sounds like you have a hierarchical vocabulary.  Good.

Now, I'd just have one single term reference field on your node.  No need to have one for the first level and one for the second level of your vocab.  Just have ONE term reference field, and set that single term reference field to take an unlimited (or whatever number greater than 1) number of values in the 'Manage fields' page of your content type.  (It won't just take one for the parent and one for the child, but both can be set once).

Download and install the [Feeds Tamper module](http://drupal.org/project/feeds_tamper), which allows you to process results in various ways during the feeds import.  Once your feeds tamper module is installed, when you go to /admin/structure/feeds, you should see a 'Tamper' link where you can configure your tamper settings.

For this to work properly, I'm assuming you can make your import file be in the form of '**Apples;Green**' for the hierarchical terms -- i.e. that you can provide them in one column, separated by a special character, and that that column is mapped to your one single term reference field.  If you can do that, then you can set your tamper to parse them out and set both the parent and child of the vocabulary this way.

Go to the '**Tamper**' link, find the field that represents this taxonomy and select 'Add plugin'.  Then select the '**Explode**' plugin and specify the special character that will separate your parent/child terms.

Test with an import, and let me know if that gets it working properly....

Comment: 1. I have a "node processor" feed. 
2. created csv for testing with 
"Subcategorie"
"Wonen;Badjas" ="parent;child"
3: setup feeds tamper Explode with String separator ";"
4: import cvs from site/import (file upload)
5: nodes are created,
6: Terms 'Wonen' and 'Badjas' are created without parent-child relations

Comment: Oh, I see what you're saying.  But aren't these terms already parent-child when you created them?  I think I misunderstood.  I thought you already had the vocabulary built up, but it sounds like you're creating terms on the fly... that's a bit different.

Comment: Otherwise, you know that you can have hierarchical (parent-child) vocabulary terms if you create them yourself beforehand, right?  You can do that by filling in the 'Relationship' portion on the term creation page...

Comment: I just thought of the misunderstanding you talked about.
My taxonomy/vocabulary is empty on node creation.
my field_category creates the parent term and my field_subcategory creates a child term. So no terms are in the vocabulary before node creation/feed import.
I know i can created the term on forehand, but that is way too much work. All needs to be created on the fly. Thats why i tried the module in my earlier response. BUt that creates errors

Comment: Still no solution for this....

Comment: If you haven't built up your vocab with its parent/child relationships in advance of the feed import, I don't know of a module which can do that for you. The feeds module will map fields to your content type, but it can't go in and administer your vocab for you (by setting parents to children). That's a totally separate action from just mapping/setting fields. I'd consider building up the vocab prior to the import or trying to achieve what you want by having 2 separate term references that are not parent/child. Your only other option would be writing your own module to achieve what you want

Answer (score 0):

I used the [Hierarchical taxonomy module](https://www.drupal.org/project/hierarchical_taxonomy). Now I can import feeds with parent ***/child*** taxonomy using it AND the [Feeds Tamper module](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_tamper).
It works perfect; you only need one import run.